# ImportError guardian: cannot import name register

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

This is from apache2-server error log:

```
File "/srv/www/maikkma/targetor/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

[targetor_upgrade@targetorpro.fi] out:
import django.template.loaders.app_directories

[targetor_upgrade@targetorpro.fi] out:
File "/srv/www/maikkma/targetor/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 25, in <module>

raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))

[targetor_upgrade@targetorpro.fi] out:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
ImportError guardian: cannot import name register

[targetor_upgrade@targetorpro.fi] out:
Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: /srv/www/maikkma/targetor/env/bin/python 
/srv/www/maikkma/targetor/manage.py 
migrate --all --no-initial-data --settings=settings.local_settings

Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /srv/www/maikkma/targetor/env/bin/ && 
. /srv/www/maikkma/targetor/env/bin/activate && 
/srv/www/maikkma/targetor/env/bin/python /srv/www/mai$
```

This django-guardian is a third party application and I think this missing register is a django-admin module?

How I can fix this error? I can't find any solution with google

Comment: Please, use proper formatting for errors ("Code sample" button in the editor).

Answer (score 0):

I find a answer to my question. My django version number is 1.6.1 and this latest django-guardian (1.4.0 or newer) reguires django 1.7 or newer.